# Generating bit stream in hardware. Glitches with Arduino

Tags: arduino, bit-bang

**Background**

I have a bit sequence that I want to transmit through a digital output. My first attempt was to use direct port assignment on an Arduino. I set the duration of each level with noops. For example, if I wanted to transmit the sequence [1, 0] with 3 clock cycles per bit the code would be

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
PORTD = B10000000;
__asm__("nop\n\t");
__asm__("nop\n\t");
PORTD = B00000000;
__asm__("nop\n\t");
__asm__("nop\n\t");
delay(1);
}
```

I am trying to transmit 3 periods of the sequence [1,1,0] with a bit width of 1us. The expected output is shown in the first picture below. The problem is that the Arduino glitches occasionally. The problem can be seen by turning on the scope persistence; see the second scope shot below.

I have scope trigger hold off set to just greater than the duration of the entire sequence (10us). [image]

[image]

**Questions**

1. Why is the Arduino glitching?
2. Is there a way to implement this on the Arduino without the glitches?
3. Is there a preferred way of generating a digital signal in hardware that works better than this?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably the timer interrupt which updates millis()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interrupt is probably occurring in the middle of your sequence. If you really want to precisely control the timing of your pulses you should disable interrupts before starting the first pulse and enable the interrupts after the last pulse.

Comment: Turning off interrupts fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Could you then "accept" my answer?

Comment: Is it not best practice to wait a bit before accepting answers, or does that only apply to less simple questions?

Comment: Sure, you can wait awhile but it's best not to forget and leave the question without an accepted answer.

Comment: I won’t forget.